# yandex metrica waiting long times

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, yandex

Yandex metricas watch.js waiting long time in my sites. Chrome network monitor file status is pending.

"Provisional headers are shown"

[image]

chrome developer tools network tab screenshot:
[image]